# Difference between "//span[not(text()='a')]" and "//span[text()!='a']"

Tags: java, selenium, xpath, selenium-webdriver, negation

I am using Selenium and Java to write a test.

What is the difference between

```
List<WebElement> wes = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.
        visibilityOfAllElementsLocatedBy(By.xpath("//span[not(text()='a')]")));
```

and

```
List<WebElement> wes = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.
        visibilityOfAllElementsLocatedBy(By.xpath("//span[text()!='a']")));
```

The first one throws error saying that it found nothing while the bottom one brings me all spans whose text is not 'a'.

Comment: Who says there is any? This would be fairly simple to test yourself....

Comment: The top one does not work, it throws error saying that I found nothing while the bottom one brings me all spans whose text is not 'a'

Comment: [This answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4629660/622391) may help you to understand what's happening.

Comment: still does not work :( someone help please