# How to refer to the origin value of the dot operator of XPath?

Tags: xml, xpath

Here is my document:

```
<library>
  <reserved>
    <book>Don Quixot</book>
  </reserved>
  <all>
    <book>Don Quixot</book>
    <book>War and Peace</book>
  </all>
</library>
```

I'm trying to select all books that are not reserved now:

```
/library/all/book[not(/library/reserved/book[.=current()])]
```

This doesn't work, since `current()` inside the second pair of squared brackets already is inside the scope of `reserved` elements. What should I use instead of `current()`?

Comment: it might be just a typo, but your XML has different opening and closing tags

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I'm trying to select all books that are not reserved now:

**Answer:**

```
/library/all/book[not(text() = /library/reserved/book/text())]
```

My previous answer did not work in all cases (see @MichaelKay's comment).

The reason why my struck-out answer does not work is because the predicate is trying to find *at least one node in the node-set selected with `reserved/book/text()` with a text that is not equal to the current text()*. This is different from *finding a book where there does **not** exist a reserved book with the same text.*

The predicate in my new answer will attempt to find a reserved book with the same text, and upon failing to do so (whether there are no reserved books or none of the reserved books have the same text, `not()` will negate the `false` result and return the book that is not reserved.

See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4629660/1623885) answer on another question for further explanation.

From the [spec](https://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-xpath-19991116/#booleans):

> If one object to be compared is a node-set and the other is a string, then the comparison will be true if and only if there is a node in the node-set such that the result of performing the comparison on the string-value of the node and the other string is true.

The `!=` operator will attempt to return `true` if it finds *at least one node with a different text*. The `=` operator will attempt to return `true` if at least one node has the same text. Both will return `false` if the node-set is empty. Therefore, the solution is to return `true` if there are no reserved books (empty node-set), or if none of the reserved books have the same text, ergo `not(text() = /library/reserved/book/text())`.

<s>If it is guaranteed that no two `<book>` elements in each list will have the same text content, then this will work:</s>

```
/library/all/book[text() != ../../reserved/book/text()]
```

Comment: Wrong. That finds a book if there is a book with a different title that is reserved. You can see this gives the wrong answer if you test it on a file where there are no reserved books, or two reserved books. You want /library/all/book[not(text() = ../../reserved/book/text())]

Comment: @MichaelKay you are correct. I'm currently checking and cannot find explanation for why `not(text() = ../../reserved/book/text())` behaves different from the answer I provided.