# Marklogic How to exclude multiple nodes in xml

Tags: marklogic

I have syntax errors when exclude  multiple nodes in element like "Sources" and "Navigators" nodes.  But it works if I exclude only one node but not combine before returning the documents.

```
[(fn:local-name()  != ("Sources","Navigators")]
```

In Marklogic Qconsole:

```
  for $x in $uris
  let $doc := fn:doc($x)
  let $copymeta := <meta:Metadata> 
                    { $doc//meta:Metadata/*[(fn:local-name() != ("Sources","Navigators")] }
                   </meta:Metadata> 
  let $newxml := <omd:record>
                   { $copymeta }
                 </omd:record>
  return $newxml
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a open parenthesis too many in front of `fn:local-name()`.

However, you could also make use of the `except` keyword, and a prefix wildcard. You would use it like this:

```
for $x in $uris
let $doc := fn:doc($x)
let $copymeta := <meta:Metadata> 
                   { $doc//meta:Metadata/(* except (*:Sources, *:Navigators)) }
                 </meta:Metadata> 
let $newxml := <omd:record>
                 { $copymeta }
               </omd:record>
return $newxml
```

HTH!

Answer (score 2):

The `!=` operator has unintuitive semantics. See [this previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4629416/xpath-operator-how-does-it-work). When the code finds a *:Sources node, it evaluates as `!=` to "Navigators", and when it finds a *:Navigators node, it evaluates as `!=` to "Sources". And then you get all the nodes.

If you aren't comparing node sequences (so `except` is not an option), then instead of `!=`, you can use `fn:not(A = B)` to get the intended effect. In this case, `fn:not(fn:local-name() = ("Sources","Navigators"))` should work as you expect.